# ROS Answers SE migration: Using services

Tags: ros, rosservice, service

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
could someone explain me how services works? I understood that messages work whith topics, so for allowing the communication among nodes.

and services? request and response?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12648/using-services/) by [Maurizio88](https://answers.ros.org/users/1359/maurizio88/) on ROS Answers with karma: 155 on 2012-01-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-16**:
@Maurizio You have gone through the ROS tutorials ? Right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try reading [this overview](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Services), and [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UnderstandingServicesParams).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4